# How to merge a remote feature branch into master using smartgit

Tags: git, git-merge, smartgit, aws-codecommit

I am using Amazon's CodeCommit repository. I have a `master` branch. I created a feature branch. Now that the development is complete in the feature branch, I want to merge those changes to `master`.

AWS CodeCommit console doesn't have an option for all the Git operations. So, I have just started using SmartGit to connect to CodeCommit. Can anybody guide how can I achieve it using SmartGit or even command line ?

I would prefer not to check out all the code first to my local machine. Can I do it remotely?

Comment: Why do you not want to check out the code locally? Because of the repo size? It looks like SmartGit is a GUI client, so how are you connecting it to CodeCommit? Does CodeCommit give you full SSH access?

Comment: SmartGit (and most likely no other Git client) will be able to perform a remote merge. You will always have to clone the repository, then perform the merge and push the changes back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible remotely. You have to clone the repository and can then just use *Finish Feature* form the Git Flow Menu if your Repository is configured for Git Flow:

[image]